# too few template-parameter-lists -- specialization of template method, g++

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++, specialization

Porting code from gcc 2.95.3 to gcc 4.4.2 results in a new compile time error:

```
too few template-parameter-lists
```

Below is an abstracted and simplified example of that code. The error occurs on the marked line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class SomeType> class SomeTemplate
{
  public:
    SomeType msg;
    void Func ();
};

void SomeTemplate<long>::Func ()        //--- Error Here ---
{
    cout << "SomeType size: " << sizeof (msg) << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    SomeTemplate<long> MyType;
    MyType.Func ();
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: `template<>` seems to be missing.

Comment: Clang gives a better message: `"template specialization requires 'template<>'"`

Comment: @WhozCraig This should be an answer.

Comment: g++-4.6 says: `specializing member ‘SomeTemplate<long int>::Func’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax`

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
template <>
void SomeTemplate<long>::Func ()        
{
    cout << "SomeType size: " << sizeof (msg) << endl;
}
```